# How to test if a Facebook user has installed my android application with sdk 3

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android application that will have Facebook integration.
Users of my application will be able to invite their friends to install my application.
How do I tell which of my users Facebook friends already have my android application installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record in a server (google app engine for example) all the users that have installed your app with the Facebook id, then you do a request to get a list of your Facebook friends ID's, then you do you compare which ID is in both list and you got them.

Comment: i had thought of that, however doesnt Facebook record what apps a Facebook user has installed? As facebook allows my application to send Request notifications to friends, to invite them to install my application is there no way to use (say) the Graph API field = "installed" to discover if a particular facebook user has my application installed?

Comment: It makes more sense right :) [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/multi-friend-selector/) Here Facebook answer your question